# How to add a new network device on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

My VPS is assigned two IPs but "ip a" shows only one real network interface eth0 and one loopback interface lo. I copy `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` and edit it to reflect the new ip. But `systemctl restart network` fails with the error: `Bringing up interface eth1:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.`

So how can I add a new device for setting up eth1? Or, I cannot add a new device without adding another real network adapter? Then, can  I assign the two IPs to the same interface eth0? How?

Update:

I follow @A.B's method but still cannot make it work:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO0=none
NAME0=eth0
DEVICE0=eth0
ONBOOT0=yes
PREFIX0=24
IPADDR0=x.x.x.x
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY0=x.x.x.1

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO1=none
NAME1=eth1
DEVICE1=eth1
ONBOOT1=yes
PREFIX1=24
IPADDR1=y.y.y.y
NETMASK1=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY1=y.y.y.1
```

The following configuration is not working as well:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO0=none
NAME0=eth0
DEVICE0=eth0
ONBOOT0=yes
PREFIX0=24
IPADDR0=x.x.x.x
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY0=x.x.x.1

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO1=none
NAME1=eth0:1
DEVICE1=eth0
ONBOOT1=yes
PREFIX1=24
IPADDR1=y.y.y.y
NETMASK1=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY1=y.y.y.1
```

The `systemctl restart network` command succeeds but `ifconfig` shows only one interface eth0 and one lo interface.

Update:

Use the corrected configuration in @A.B's answer and use `ip a`, it works! The two ips are shown under the interface eth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the two IP addresses on the *same* interface.

This was documented in [RHEL 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces) but doesn't appear anymore in RHEL 7's documentation. Presumably this configuration is being phased out (eg: to the use of NetworkManager and `nmtui`) so this less frequent setting isn't officially documented anymore. As usual it's exactly the same with CentOS 6/CentOS 7.

> IPADDRn=address
>
> where address is the IPv4 address and the n is expected to be consecutive positive integers starting from 0 (for example, IPADDR0).
> It is used for configurations with **multiple IP addresses on *an*
> interface**. It can be omitted if there is only one address being
> configured.

The content of the script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions` shows it's still valid syntax:

> ```
> expand_config ()
> {
>     local i=0 val
>     for idx in '' {0..255} ; do
>         ipaddr[$i]=$(eval echo '$'IPADDR$idx)
>         if [ -z "${ipaddr[$i]}" ]; then
>             [ "$idx" ] && [ $idx -ge 2 ] && break
>             continue
>         fi
>         prefix[$i]=$(eval echo '$'PREFIX$idx)
>         netmask[$i]=$(eval echo '$'NETMASK$idx)
>         broadcast[$i]=$(eval echo '$'BROADCAST$idx)
>         arpcheck[$i]=$(eval echo '$'ARPCHECK$idx)
>         arpupdate[$i]=$(eval echo '$'ARPUPDATE$idx)
> ```

So in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` just change `IPADDR=` into `IPADDR0=` plus `IPADDR1=` and do the same for other similar settings in the list just above (eg: if you were using `NETMASK=` , change it into `NETMASK0=` plus `NETMASK1=` etc.).

**UPDATE** (after OP made configuration contents available): The only entries concerned *in the list just above* are these (only if initially used):

```
PREFIX
NETMASK
BROADCAST
ARPCHECK
ARPUPDATE
```

not any other and in particular not:

- `NAME`

  There is only **one** interface. In addition using alias addresses as interface (eg: `eth0:1`) should absolutely be avoided, it's an obsolete concept that has become useless and prone to mistakes when configuring other settings. It was never suggested in this answer.
- `GATEWAY`

  There is only **one** default route (even when actually having multiple interfaces which is not the case here). Multi-homing where two different separate routes to Internet are possible is a different beast and can't be answered in this same question here.

Then in the end the `ifconfig` command should never be used (it's part of the obsolete API that cannot display correctly multiple IPv4 addresses (on a single interface) that don't have a compatibility label). Instead use:

```
ip address
```

or `ip -br address` to display the configured addresses on the host interface(s). Likewise the command to display routes on Linux should better be:

```
ip route
```

instead of `route`.

---

In the end the configuration in `ifcfg-eth0` should (only) be:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX0=24
IPADDR0=x.x.x.x
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
PREFIX1=24
IPADDR1=y.y.y.y
NETMASK1=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=x.x.x.1
```

The same gateway x.x.x.1 will in the end be used even for routing the y.y.y.y address, unless the host provider provided a detailed routing documentation telling otherwise (and in which case this would require a separate question anyway, because the configuration isn't only about `ifcfg-eth0` anymore and is difficult to grasp). It's even possible that the 2nd address's prefix/netmask PREFIX1 should be 32 instead of 24 (and redundant NETMASK1 then 255.255.255.255), but this can't be known without the host provider's documentation and probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I follow your method but still cannot make it work. Please see the updated configuration.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly to specify what went wrong and must not be done.

Comment: Your configuration works, thanks! By the way, is the device eth0 bound to the hardware, i.e., the network adapter? Cannot I create a new device like eth1 at will?

Comment: It really depends on what is your VPS. You can install the package virt-what and run the command virt-what to know if your system is bare metal, a VM or a container. This probably involves your host provider (and maybe money). There are also ways to create a new interface on the system directly (if the system isn't a restricted container), but without a precise use case to explain why there should be one, I don't see the need.